# attached file is coming blank on upload button

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am checking a `filename` after clicking on upload button. But it is coming blank and giving me error as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I don't know why I am not getting the filename even after uploading it.

I am uploading a `.jpg` image. below is the code:-

```
protected void BtnUpload_out_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    string Datafile = ""; 
     HttpPostedFile PF_File; 
    string Filename = "";   // filename is blank here

    if (FileUpload_out.PostedFile.FileName != "") // here I get reference error
    {

        if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Transactions/FileAttachment/" + hidAttachid.Value + "/VO/" + FileUpload_out.FileName)) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Transactions/FileAttachment/" + hidAttachid.Value + "/VO"));
        }}
```

Comment: Is your `FileUpload_out` wrapped inside update panel?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: yes, all my html is wrapped inside update panel

Comment: Can you share the mark-up?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: I tried removing that and check it again. It worked for me. Why it was not working coz of `UpdatePanel` any special reason ?

Comment: AJAX update panel is used to prevent the page to have the full postback. So, during partial page postback, it sends an async  request to server because of this file upload control doesn't work when it is asynchronous postback. In order to make it work you need `PostBackTrigger`

Comment: can you add and give me that `PostBackTrigger` part in my jsfiddle. I need to work with `updatePanel` in future. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8wnt6tzy/

Answer (score 0):

AJAX update panel is used to prevent the page to have the full postback. Using update panel we can have partial page postback. Partial page postback does the following

1.Improves the performance of the application

2.Decrease the page load time of the application

3.Decreases the round trip between the application and server

4.Only the section in web page which needs to be refreshed gets postback

We know that we can upload file to server using File upload control. However, if we use file upload control inside update panel, then it doesn't works. The reason for this is that file upload control doesn't work with asynchronous postback.

add this to your form tag and then add trigger as shown

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
.....
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "uploadbuttonID"/>     
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
.....
```